# Zend validate interprets "disabled" input fields as empty

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-validate

I again ran into a problem I just can´t seem to comprehend. 
I have a form element like so:

```
$this->add(array(
        'type'    => 'datetime',
        'name'    => 'modifiedTime',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Modified Time',
            ),
         'attributes' => array(
            'disabled' => 'disable',
            ),

        ));
```

This one does get filled correctly trough my entity(I am using doctrine) like so:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true, name="modified_time") 
 * 
 * @Form\Exclude()
 */
protected $modifiedTime;

public function getModifiedTime(){
    return $this->modifiedTime;
}

public function populate($data)
{
$this->modifiedTime = date_create($data['modifiedTime']);
}
```

This works completly fine as long as the "disabled" attribute is not set. But as soon as it is I get a validation error claiming "Value is required and can't be empty" eventhou the value is set in the input.

any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The disabled attribute does exactly what it states. It disables the html-form-element. This means, that when you sent the form back to your service/controller, that form field will **not** be posted.

Now my assumption is that you don't want users to edit some data that's displayed in an EditForm? In this case, don't use `disabled`, better choose `readonly` for displaying purpose.

On Server-Side, simply ignore what the user is posting. As when it's readonly, the data will still be sent and can be modified by the user using browser-dev-tools ;)

Comment: this is correct, but the validation on a readonly field is not considered. I have a readonly field where I select a date from a datepicker to avoid mistyping of a date. This field is required but if left empty the validation has no impact on it.